# How to show tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, command, database-table, dbtable

What's the equivalent to `show tables` (from MySQL) in PostgreSQL?

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1288/90651

Comment: \dt [postgresql-show-tables](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-administration/postgresql-show-tables/)

Answer (score 3517, accepted):

From the `psql` command line interface,

First, choose your database

```
\c database_name
```

Then, this shows all tables in the current schema:

```
\dt
```

---

Programmatically (or from the `psql` interface too, of course):

```
SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables;
```

The system tables live in the `pg_catalog` database.

Comment: @StephenCorwin No, `\l` is the equivalent of `show databases` in MySQL.  
`dt` ≃ `show tables` and  
`l` ≃ `show databases`

Comment: `\dt` is very useful.  That `pg_catalog.pg_tables` one is much less so, as it appears to lump internal tables together with the user-created ones for whatever database you happen to be connected to.

Comment: `psql my_db_name` should be run in order `\dt` to work. When I ran `psql` without a database name, I got a "No relations found" message

Comment: Without system tables: `SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE schemaname != 'pg_catalog' AND schemaname != 'information_schema'`

Comment: You first need `\c <DATABASE_NAME>` to choose your database.

Comment: To remember this, think `\dt` == Display Tables.

Comment: Sounds useful to me to add that the result has to be [q]uit with the `q` key

Comment: You also need to specify the schema to use, e.g.: \dt my_schema.*

Comment: This answer is incomplete. Please add the answer below ... \c etc.

Comment: Error: no such table: pg_catalog.pg_tables

Comment: You can also show more information about a specific table in the database using `\d++ TABLE_NAME;`, but first, you need to be in the specific database you need to see the table in using `\c DATABASE_NAME`.

Comment: Is there an explanation somewhere why the psql syntax is so unorthodox for an SQL DB client? I wonder what's the reasoning behind these backslashes, did they do it on purpose?
I've to google it but to no avail.

Comment: Also, output of `Did not find any relations.` just means there are no tables in the schema.

Answer (score 237):

You can use PostgreSQL's interactive terminal Psql to show tables in PostgreSQL.

**1. Start Psql**

Usually you can run the following command to enter into psql:

```
psql DBNAME USERNAME
```

For example, `psql template1 postgres`

One situation you might have is: suppose you login as root, and you don't remember the database name. You can just enter first into Psql by running:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

In some systems, sudo command is not available, you can instead run either command below:

```
psql -U postgres
psql --username=postgres
```

**2. Show tables**

Now in Psql you could run commands such as:

1. `\?` list all the commands
2. `\l` list databases
3. `\conninfo` display information about current connection
4. `\c [DBNAME]` connect to new database, e.g., `\c template1`
5. `\dt` list tables of the public schema
6. `\dt <schema-name>.*` list tables of certain schema, e.g., `\dt public.*`
7. `\dt *.*` list tables of all schemas
8. Then you can run SQL statements, e.g., `SELECT * FROM my_table;`(Note: a statement must be terminated with semicolon `;`)
9. `\q` quit psql

Comment: "psql -U postgres" will log and connect to "postgres" database

Comment: `\d+` Details about the table.
`\x` Displays the output in an expanded way. (Retype `\x` to turn the expanded display off)

Comment: @sina `\du` has nothing to do with listing tables, which is what the question is asking about. There are many more psql commands not listed here.

Answer (score 227):

Login as superuser:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

You can list all databases and users by `\l` command, (list other commands by `\?`).

Now if you want to see other databases you can change user/database by `\c` command like `\c template1`, `\c postgres postgres` and use `\d`, `\dt` or `\dS` to see tables/views/etc.

Answer (score 165):

(For completeness)

You could also query the (SQL-standard) [information schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html):

```
SELECT
    table_schema || '.' || table_name
FROM
    information_schema.tables
WHERE
    table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
AND
    table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');
```

Comment: +1 although for completeness, mysql show tables only shows the current schema,  its good to think of it this way, mysql only has one database but multiple schemas, where postgresql can have mutliple databases (catalogs) and schemas.  So the equiv should be table_schema='DB_NAME';

Comment: Not exactly standard sql, cannot use "||" to concatenate strings on mssql

Comment: @ChRoNoN: that **is** standard SQL . `||` has been the string concatenation operator in the SQL standard since 1983 - it's MS SQL that uses a non-standard string concatenation operator.

Answer (score 58):

Login as a superuser so that you can check all the databases and their schemas:-

```
sudo su - postgres
```

Then we can get to postgresql shell by using following command:-

```
psql
```

You can now check all the databases list by using the following command:-

```
\l
```

If you would like to check the sizes of the databases as well use:-

```
\l+
```

Press `q` to go back.

Once you have found your database now you can connect to that database using the following command:-

```
\c database_name
```

Once connected you can check the database tables or schema by:-

```
\d
```

Now to return back to the shell use:-

```
q
```

Now to further see the details of a certain table use:-

```
\d table_name
```

To go back to postgresql_shell press `\q`.

And to return back to terminal press `exit`.

Comment: This is a nice quick starter fir someone not familiar with pgsql

Answer (score 56):

1. First login as postgres user:

   `sudo su - postgres`
2. connect to the required db: `psql -d databaseName`
3. `\dt` would return the list of all table in the database you're connected to.

Answer (score 45):

Running psql with the -E flag will echo the query used internally to implement
\dt and similar:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -E

postgres=# \dt       
********* QUERY **********
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
c.relname as "Name", 
CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'i' THEN 'index' WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence' WHEN 's' THEN 'special' END as "Type",
pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) as "Owner"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
    LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','')
    AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
    AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
    AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
ORDER BY 1,2;        
**************************
```

Comment: BTW, TOAST is used to store large values: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/storage-toast.html

Answer (score 26):

If you only want to see the list of tables you've created, you may only say:

`\dt`

But we also have `PATTERN` which will help you customize which tables to show. To show all including `pg_catalog` Schema, you can add `*`.

`\dt *`

If you do: `\?`

> \dt[S+] [PATTERN]      list tables

Answer (score 26):

use only see a tables

```
=> \dt
```

if want to see schema tables

```
=>\dt+
```

if you want to see specific schema tables

```
=>\dt schema_name.*
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're confusing `+` with `S`. The latter (the letter) shows schema tables. The `+` simply shows extra information.

Answer (score 26):

(MySQL) shows tables list for current database

```
show tables;
```

(PostgreSQL) shows tables list for current database

```
select * from pg_catalog.pg_tables where schemaname='public';
```

Answer (score 20):

If you are using pgAdmin4 in PostgreSQL, you can use this to show the tables in your database:

```
select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema='public';
```

Answer (score 19):

First Connect with the Database using following command

```
\c database_name
```

And you will see this message - `You are now connected to database database_name`. And them run the following command

```
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

In database_name and table_name just update with your database and table name

Comment: I'm not sure this is answering the question. I think the OP is (was) trying to know all the tables in his database, not get all the rows from a particular table in his database... right?

Answer (score 17):

```
select 
  * 
from 
  pg_catalog.pg_tables 
where 
  schemaname != 'information_schema' 
  and schemaname != 'pg_catalog';
```

Answer (score 14):

Note that `\dt` alone will list tables in the **public** schema of the database you're using. I like to keep my tables in separate schemas, so the accepted answer didn't work for me.

To list all tables *within a specific schema*, I needed to:

1) Connect to the desired database:

```
psql mydb
```

2) Specify the schema name I want to see tables for after the `\dt` command, like this:

```
\dt myschema.*
```

This shows me the results I'm interested in:

```
               List of relations
 Schema   |       Name      | Type  |  Owner   
----------+-----------------+-------+----------
 myschema | users           | table | postgres
 myschema | activity        | table | postgres
 myschema | roles           | table | postgres
```

Answer (score 14):

Those steps worked for me with `PostgreSQL 13.3` and `Windows 10`

1. Open cmd and type `psql -a -U [username] -p [port] -h [server]`
2. Type `\c [database]` to connect to the database
3. Type `\dt` or `\d` to show all tables

Answer (score 12):

`\dt` will list tables, and `\pset pager off` shows them in the same window, without switching to a separate one. Love that feature to death in dbshell.

Answer (score 9):

\dt (no * required) -- will list all tables for an existing database you are already connected to. Also useful to note:

\d [table_name] -- will show all columns for a given table including type information, references and key constraints.

Answer (score 8):

The most straightforward way to list all tables at command line is, for my taste :

```
psql -a -U <user> -p <port> -h <server> -c "\dt"
```

For a given database just add the database name :

```
psql -a -U <user> -p <port> -h <server> -c "\dt" <database_name>
```

It works on both Linux and Windows.

Comment: command="\d+"
psql_command="psql --no-password -d "ch_api_db" -U "ch_api_user" -c "${command}""
docker exec -it "${container_name}" sh -c "${psql_command}"
gives me an error about syntax error near d

Answer (score 8):

This SQL Query works with most of the versions of PostgreSQL and fairly simple .

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema='public' ;
```

Comment: Don't post duplicate answers.

Comment: it isn't duplicate  there is small change this directly gives the table name , i tired to edit the original answer but it wasn't  approved hence gave an answer which works

Comment: The answer by Milen A. Radev provides the table_name. The answer by Reynante Daitol contains the rest of this code. If you believe that this code offers something new and unique that is a reason to include an explanation that points that out. Without the explanation people are left guessing why it is different or potentially better.

Answer (score 7):

You can list the tables in the current database with `\dt`.

Fwiw, `\d tablename` will show details about the given table, something like `show columns from tablename` in MySQL, but with a little more information.

Answer (score 6):

as a "quick oneliner"

```
# how-to list all the tables 
export PGUSER='postgres'
export PGHOST='postgres-host-end-point'
export PGPORT=5432
export PGDATABASE=foobar

PGPASSWORD='uber-secret' psql -d $PGDATABASE -t -q -c \
 "SELECT table_catalog,table_schema,table_name 
   FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema='public';
```

or if you prefer much clearer json output multi-liner :

```
IFS='' read -r -d '' sql_code <<"EOF_CODE"
    select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t))) from (
        SELECT table_catalog,table_schema,table_name 
        FROM information_schema.tables
        ORDER BY table_schema,table_name ) t
EOF_CODE
psql -d postgres -t -q -c "$sql_code"|jq
```

Answer (score 6):

1. In PostgreSQL command-line interface after login, type the following command to connect with the desired database.

   ```
       \c [database_name]
   ```

Then you will see this message `You are now connected to database "[database_name]"`

2. Type the following command to list all the tables.

   ```
       \dt
   ```

Answer (score 6):

These list all tables of all schemas of the current database:

```
\dt *.*
```

```
\dtS *.*
```

These list all tables of all schemas of the current database in detail:

```
\dt+ *.*
```

```
\dtS+ *.*
```

These list all tables of `pg_catalog` and [public](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PUBLIC) schemas of the current database:

```
\dtS
```

```
\dtS *
```

```
\dt *
```

These list all tables of `pg_catalog` and `public` schemas of the current database in detail:

```
\dtS+
```

```
\dtS+ *
```

```
\dt+ *
```

This lists all tables of `public` schema of the current database:

```
\dt
```

This lists all tables of `public` schema of the current database in detail:

```
\dt+
```

These list all tables of `my_schema` schema of the current database:

```
\dtS my_schema.*
```

```
\dt my_schema.*
```

These list all tables of `my_schema` schema of the current database in detail:

```
\dtS+ my_schema.*
```

```
\dt+ my_schema.*
```

Answer (score 5):

---

Using **psql** : \dt

Or:

```
SELECT c.relname AS Tables_in FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
        LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
        AND c.relkind = 'r'
        AND relname NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all you have to connect with your database like

my database is **ubuntu**

use this command to connect

```
 \c ubuntu
```

This message will show

> "You are now connected to database "ubuntu" as user "postgres"."

Now

Run this command to show all tables in it

```
\d+
```

Answer (score 1):

**\dt** will work. And the equivalence of it is

```
SELECT
  n.nspname as "Schema",
  c.relname as "Name",
  CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'm' THEN 'materialized view' WHEN 'i' THEN 'index' WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence' WHEN 's' THEN 'special' WHEN 'f' THEN 'foreign table' WHEN 'p' THEN 'partitioned table' WHEN 'I' THEN 'partitioned index' END as "Type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) as "Owner"
FROM
  pg_catalog.pg_class c
  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE
  c.relkind IN ('r', 'p', '')
  AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
  AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
  AND n.nspname ! ~ '^pg_toast'
  AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

To view foreign tables in psql, run `\dE`

Answer (score 0):

Also note this from the [pgAdmin documentation](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/modifying_tables.html):

> pgAdmin 4 provides dialogs that allow you to modify all table properties and attributes.
>
> To access a dialog that allows you to create a database object, right-click on the object type in the pgAdmin tree control, and select the Create option for that object. For example, to create a new table, Select a database from the tree control, select the schema under the database, right-click on the Tables node, and select Create Table.

So once you've done that (or you could also use SQL commands and the pSQL client) and you have some tables, you can view them by expanding the "Schemas" object in the pgAdmin UI. Here's a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image: Tables in pgAdmin 4 UI]

After selecting a table, you may also click on "View Data" at the top toolbar (the one with the grid table icon) to view the table's records.

Answer (score -1):

First you can connect with your postgres database using the postgre.app on mac or using postico.
Run the following command:

```
psql -h localhost -p port_number -d database_name -U user_name -W
```

then you enter your password, this should give access to your database