# what does run the command \dt mean?

Tags: django

I'm teaching myself django.  At this site

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/

It says

If you’re interested, run the command-line client for your database and type \dt (PostgreSQL), SHOW TABLES; (MySQL), .schema (SQLite), or SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES; (Oracle) to display the tables Django created.

I really don't know what that means.  Do they want me to input some commands in the terminal?  If so what commands?

Comment: "Run the command-line client for your database". Look it up in the manual of whatever database you're using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show tables in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769683/show-tables-in-postgresql)

Comment: Not sure why this question got downvoted. I think PO stated his/her question quite clearly. I think sometimes StackOverflow is too harsh to beginners.

Comment: @AKX Related but not a duplicate. Goal of OP is not to show all tables, but to understand what the \dt command will accomplish in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a Django or Python function, it is a PostgreSQL one. If you don't use PostgreSQL, this is not relevant to you.

If you do use PostgreSQL and would like to know more about its command-line client, you should [check out the official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-psql.html): basically, it is a program that will allow you to connect to your database and issue SQL commands (such as `SELECT ...`, `UPDATE ...`) directly, as well as a few non-SQL additions such as listing all tables (`\dt`), list view (`\dv`), or exit (`\q`).

Other SQL systems have their own version of those non-SQL commands, for example MySQL uses `SHOW TABLES;`, and SQLite3 uses `.tables`. Use the correct one for your system.

Answer (score 1):

### `\dt` lists all tables in a PostgreSQL database.

The command is run within [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-psql.html), the command-line tool installed with Postgres.

Here are the steps to run `\dt` successfully. (Note that Steps 1 and 2 aren't necessary but may be helpful for learning purposes):

1. Access psql from your terminal by typing `psql -U postgres`. This allows you to access the psql CLI with access to all local databases.
2. Input `\l` to list all local databases
3. Input `psql db_name` to access a particular database
4. Input `\dt` - this will show all the tables in the database

If you already know the name of the database you can simply type `psql db_name` from the terminal and `\dt` thereafter.