# Is SHOW statement in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

In [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show.html) document, it lists `SHOW` statements (for tables, databases, ...) in "SQL".

But PostgreSQL doesn't have `SHOW` or equivalent statement in PL/pgsql. Only `psql` has some [client-side commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/769706/156458) for the same purpose.

So I was wondering 
whether `SHOW` statements are in SQL, or in MySQL's SQL dialect?

Thanks

Comment: If you need to do it in SQL you'd query the system tables. There's an option for `psql` that will show you the SQL behind `\dt` and friends, just check the [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11286777/479863) to the question you linked to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `SHOW` command in standard SQL, so the MySQL and PostgreSQL `SHOW` commands are quite different.

If you need a standard conforming way to get table metadata, you should query the tables and views in the [`information_schema`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html).

Answer (score 3):

Postgres has a [show statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-show.html), but it is for a different objective than MySQLs. I wouldn't worry about what is and isn't valid  SQL; the only thing I would concern myself with is what variant I'm dealing with here.

Comment: Thanks. I am concerned about if SQL has statement for showing tables, databases, ...

Comment: Now you seem to be asking for something else maybe "SELECT datname FROM pg_database ;"  ?? Please list specifically if you can't find what you need. Cheers ..

Comment: \? will list what's available.