# Does `psql` have something similar to `$PATH` in `bash` to search for a SQL script?

Tags: postgresql, psql

In psql, `\i` can be used to read and execute a sql script. 
But I have to specify a pathname to the script file to `\i`, which is very inconvenient, when pathname is long and differs from script to script.

Is there something similar to `$PATH` in `bash` for  `psql`'s `\i` to search for a script based only on the filename of a sql script?

Or do I really have to specify a pathname  to `\i` every time I run a sql script file?

Thanks.

I am trying to place https://stackoverflow.com/a/771880/156458 into a sql script, so that I can reuse it.

Answer (score 1):

Something akin to Oracle's `$SQLPATH`. I haven't found it. With Oracle it was handy so that I could define commands into separate SQL files and have them available in `sqlplus`.

With PostgreSQL and `psql`, the only suggestion I received was to put any commands as aliases in `~/.psqlrc`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give an example in ~/.psqlrc, if I have multiple scripts under `/path/to/sqlscripts/`?

Comment: No, I mean you'd literally have all of the SQL commands as aliases in `~/.psqlrc`. One big file. It's not pretty.

Comment: Possible to write a loop over all the files under the directory, and assign the filename as the alias to each file? I can do that in bash, but not sure if it can be done in psql.