# How can we show all the databases in a cluster without using `psql`'s command or option?

Tags: postgresql

https://stackoverflow.com/a/771880/156458 provides a way to show all the tables defined in a database, via information schema. Since information schema is per database, I guess it won't be useful for showing all the databases in a cluster?

How would you show all the databases in a cluster in a comparable way, i.e. without using `psql`'s command or option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Query the system catalog [`pg_database`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-database.html), e.g.:

```
select datname
from pg_database;

       datname       
---------------------
 template1
 template0
 postgres
 test
 db
 library_development
(6 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks. Does SQL standard specify something relevant, and if yes, is your way close to the SQL standard? Does it have some portability to other RDBMS, up to some minor modification?

Comment: No, the term *database* is understood differently in various RDBMS. Also, the system catalogs are specific to Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

To show all postgres databases execute the command below on console:
`sudo su - postgres -c "psql -c '\l'"`