# show list of master tables in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I need to the SQL command to list all the master tables in the Postgresql database.

I have logged into a database called OpenBravo and when I run the command

```
\dt
```

It shows all the tables created in that database. I want to see the list of tables prefixed with pg_ which are master tables carrying the schematic details I believe

I reemphasize that I need only the tables with pg_ prefix not all the tables

Comment: What do you mean by "master tables"? Do you mean the ones under the dbname postgres?

Comment: I refer to tables with the prefix pg_. Example pg_class, pg_tables etc. How do you call it in postgres? Meta tables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show tables in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769683/show-tables-in-postgresql)

Comment: As the other thread states you can log to the pg_catalog database to get them.

Comment: Did you try it? pg_catalog.pg_tables has even the user tables and info tables

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name do you have a link for the cross posted post?

Answer (score 0):

Another contributor from another forum gave the right answer

```
You can use this command: \dt pg_*
```

Some people downvote and mark it duplicate without the right experiment. SO should take action against them.