# PostgreSQL display all tables in different schema without setting search_path

Tags: postgresql, multi-tenant, dt

recently I experience on postgresql and found that \dt are not show all tables if those tables with the same name but under different schema.

example

```
test2.my_table1
test1.my_table1
```

if setting search_path, \dt will only showing the tables which inside the 1st priority schema.

this will be an very pain full to multi-tenant database management.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL: Show tables in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769683/postgresql-show-tables-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

simple use command

```
\dt *.<tale_prefix>*
```

example:

```
\dt *.my_*
```