# Data from spring application is not being persisted in the dockerized Postgres database

Tags: spring, postgresql, docker

I would really appreciate any help. I've been looking for a solution to my problem all day but I can't find anything that works. I have several docker containers: a spring application, a postgres database, keycloak, and a postgres database backup. When I create a new entity through my endpoint using Postman or curl, I can also retrieve it through another endpoint. However, nothing is being saved in the database. When I restart the spring container, all the data is gone! I just don't understand why the data is not being persisted in the database.

this is my docker-compose file:

```yaml
services:
  sales-service:
    container_name: service-container
    image: "mab123/sales-service:latest"
    environment:
      PG_HOST: postgres-container
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    networks:
      - internal
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres-container
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES: sales, keycloak
      POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: "--auth-host=scram-sha-256 --auth-local=scram-sha-256"
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
      - ./src/main/resources/pg-init-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      test: "PGPASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-postgres} pg_isready -h 127.0.0.1 -U ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres} -d sales"
    networks:
      - internal

  flyway:
    container_name: flyway
    image: flyway/flyway
    command: -url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/sales -user=postgres -password=postgres -locations=filesystem:/flyway/sql -connectRetries=60 migrate
    volumes:
      - ./src/main/resources/db/migration/:/flyway/sql/
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - internal

  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak-container
    image: "quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest"
    volumes:
      - ./src/main/resources/keycloak/realms.json:/opt/keycloak/data/import/realms.json
    env_file:
      - src/main/resources/keycloak/keycloak.env
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: unless-stopped
    entrypoint: [ "/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start-dev", "--import-realm" ]
    networks:
      internal:
        aliases:
          - keycloak.keycon.com
    depends_on:
      - postgres

volumes:
  postgres:

networks:
  internal:
```

I have not found anything that could be wrong in the docker-compose file, but if you have any ideas, please let me know.

Here are my application-dev settings:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${PG_HOST:localhost}:5432/sales
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
  flyway:
    datasources:
      default:
        enabled: true
```

PG_HOST is the name of the postgres docker container.

As previously mentioned, when I create a new entity, I receive a JSON response containing the DTO object with the assigned ID within the entity. However, when I access the Postgres database container and execute a psql command, the result displays zero rows.

[image]

Comment: That sounds like the Spring application might be using an in-memory database instead of the PostgreSQL database.  You should be able to see that in the container logs.  Do you need to enable the `dev` profile; or would it make more sense to set a `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` environment variable in the Compose setup?

Comment: Based on the log, it appears that the application is using a H2 database with a in-memory URL: "jdbc:h2:mem:3575c78f-dfa7-41e0-87d0-b2e17abb53c3".
That's strange, I don't have an h2 dependency in my pom. I will investigate and post here once I find a solution.

The Problem comes somehow from flyway:
14:38:03.677 [main] INFO  org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.base.BaseDatabaseType - Database: jdbc:h2:mem:304ba49c-f65b-4afb-8a38-eb04cc2c1951 (H2 2.1)

Comment: If possible can you create the minimal reproducible example of reproducing this issue. I tried with above config everything looks good.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue of API being able to perform POST request to Postgres docker volume and checking the inserted data gives empty rows in tables ? I'm running the same issues since yesterday without any clue of the impediments. In my case there is no in-memory database. Checking the logs I saw that my application is using the docker database. Why can't I then see the values inserted in the database table ? Thank in advance if you've been able to solve yours.

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting Topic, I never figure out but from your initial idea, it give me how to shows content from database. Thanks!

I can't browser your `sales` database due to no your `spring boot` source but I can see `keycloak` database.

This is my experiment for `keycloak` database from `postgres` docker.
I think your `sales` database not public or something wrong.

database name is `keycloak` and user is `keycloak` in Postgres
It will use later to access database.

I am sure, this steps give an idea how to see your `sales` database.
I hope to help to debug between keycloak and database.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  postgres:
      image: postgres
      volumes:
        - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
        POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  keycloak:
      image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2-legacy
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
        DB_ADDR: postgres
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_SCHEMA: public
        DB_PASSWORD: password
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
      ports:
        - 8080:8080 # Expose to user with localhost:8080
      restart: always
      depends_on:
        - postgres

volumes:
  postgres_data:  # Keycloack volume
      driver: local
```

#### #1 Step 1, get `postgres` container ID

```
docker ps -a
```

->

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                              NAMES
c48f3f8fea9f   quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2-legacy   "/opt/jboss/tools/do…"   54 minutes ago   Up 54 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 8443/tcp   docker-compose-keycloak-1
254a2038d581   postgres                                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   54 minutes ago   Up 54 minutes   5432/tcp                           docker-compose-postgres-1
```

#### #2 Step 2, go inside `postgres` container

(* note: I am using Windows git bash, `winpty` is not need in Linux)

```
winpty docker exec -it 254a2038d581 bin/bash
```

-->

```
root@254a2038d581:/#
```

#### #3 Step 3, check Linux version

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

-->

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
```

And check who am I

```
whoami
```

-->

```
root
```

#### #4 Step 4, add user 'keycloak` and add sudo user

(password is password)

```
adduser keycloak
```

-->

```
Adding user `keycloak' ...
Adding new group `keycloak' (1000) ...
Adding new user `keycloak' (1000) with group `keycloak' ...
```

```
usermod -aG sudo keycloak
```

#### #5 Step 5, switch user `keycloak` and connect database

```
su keycloak
```

-->

```
keycloak@254a2038d581:/$
```

```
psql -U keycloak -w
```

-->

```
psql (14.5 (Debian 14.5-1.pgdg110+1))
Type "help" for help.

keycloak=#
```

#### #6 Step 6, get connected information

```
 \conninfo
```

-->

```
You are connected to database "keycloak" as user "keycloak" via socket in "/var/run/postgresql" at port "5432".
```

#### #7 Step 7, list tables and schemas

```
\dt
```

-->

```
                     List of relations
 Schema |             Name              | Type  |  Owner
--------+-------------------------------+-------+----------
 public | admin_event_entity            | table | keycloak
 public | associated_policy             | table | keycloak
 public | authentication_execution      | table | keycloak
 public | authentication_flow           | table | keycloak
 public | authenticator_config          | table | keycloak
 public | authenticator_config_entry    | table | keycloak
 public | broker_link                   | table | keycloak
 public | client                        | table | keycloak
 public | client_attributes             | table | keycloak
 public | client_auth_flow_bindings     | table | keycloak
 public | client_initial_access         | table | keycloak
 public | client_node_registrations     | table | keycloak
 public | client_scope                  | table | keycloak
 public | client_scope_attributes       | table | keycloak
 public | client_scope_client           | table | keycloak
 public | client_scope_role_mapping     | table | keycloak
 public | client_session                | table | keycloak
 public | client_session_auth_status    | table | keycloak
 public | client_session_note           | table | keycloak
 public | client_session_prot_mapper    | table | keycloak
 public | client_session_role           | table | keycloak
 public | client_user_session_note      | table | keycloak
 public | component                     | table | keycloak
 public | component_config              | table | keycloak
 public | composite_role                | table | keycloak
 public | credential                    | table | keycloak
 public | databasechangelog             | table | keycloak
 public | databasechangeloglock         | table | keycloak
 public | default_client_scope          | table | keycloak
 public | event_entity                  | table | keycloak
 public | fed_user_attribute            | table | keycloak
 public | fed_user_consent              | table | keycloak
 public | fed_user_consent_cl_scope     | table | keycloak
 public | fed_user_credential           | table | keycloak
 public | fed_user_group_membership     | table | keycloak
 public | fed_user_required_action      | table | keycloak
 public | fed_user_role_mapping         | table | keycloak
 public | federated_identity            | table | keycloak
 public | federated_user                | table | keycloak
 public | group_attribute               | table | keycloak
 public | group_role_mapping            | table | keycloak
 public | identity_provider             | table | keycloak
 public | identity_provider_config      | table | keycloak
 public | identity_provider_mapper      | table | keycloak
 public | idp_mapper_config             | table | keycloak
 public | keycloak_group                | table | keycloak
 public | keycloak_role                 | table | keycloak
 public | migration_model               | table | keycloak
 public | offline_client_session        | table | keycloak
 public | offline_user_session          | table | keycloak
 public | policy_config                 | table | keycloak
 public | protocol_mapper               | table | keycloak
 public | protocol_mapper_config        | table | keycloak
 public | realm                         | table | keycloak
 public | realm_attribute               | table | keycloak
 public | realm_default_groups          | table | keycloak
 public | realm_enabled_event_types     | table | keycloak
 public | realm_events_listeners        | table | keycloak
 public | realm_localizations           | table | keycloak
 public | realm_required_credential     | table | keycloak
 public | realm_smtp_config             | table | keycloak
 public | realm_supported_locales       | table | keycloak
 public | redirect_uris                 | table | keycloak
 public | required_action_config        | table | keycloak
 public | required_action_provider      | table | keycloak
 public | resource_attribute            | table | keycloak
 public | resource_policy               | table | keycloak
 public | resource_scope                | table | keycloak
 public | resource_server               | table | keycloak
 public | resource_server_perm_ticket   | table | keycloak
 public | resource_server_policy        | table | keycloak
 public | resource_server_resource      | table | keycloak
 public | resource_server_scope         | table | keycloak
 public | resource_uris                 | table | keycloak
 public | role_attribute                | table | keycloak
 public | scope_mapping                 | table | keycloak
 public | scope_policy                  | table | keycloak
 public | user_attribute                | table | keycloak
 public | user_consent                  | table | keycloak
 public | user_consent_client_scope     | table | keycloak
 public | user_entity                   | table | keycloak
 public | user_federation_config        | table | keycloak
 public | user_federation_mapper        | table | keycloak
 public | user_federation_mapper_config | table | keycloak
 public | user_federation_provider      | table | keycloak
 public | user_group_membership         | table | keycloak
 public | user_required_action          | table | keycloak
 public | user_role_mapping             | table | keycloak
 public | user_session                  | table | keycloak
 public | user_session_note             | table | keycloak
 public | username_login_failure        | table | keycloak
 public | web_origins                   | table | keycloak
```

If you want to more information, \dt+

```
 Schema |             Name              | Type  |  Owner   | Persistence | Access method |    Size    | Description
--------+-------------------------------+-------+----------+-------------+---------------+------------+-------------
 public | admin_event_entity            | table | keycloak | permanent   | heap          | 8192 bytes |
 public | associated_policy             | table | keycloak | permanent   | heap          | 8192 bytes |
 public | authentication_execution      | table | keycloak | permanent   | heap          | 88 kB      |
 public | authentication_flow           | table | keycloak | permanent   | heap          | 64 kB      |
...
```

#### #8 Step 8, clients list and detail information

(if you query `SELECT * FROM client;` , can get all of fields)

```
SELECT name, client_id  FROM client;
```

-->

```
               name               |       client_id
----------------------------------+------------------------
 master Realm                     | master-realm
 ${client_account}                | account
 ${client_account-console}        | account-console
 ${client_broker}                 | broker
 ${client_security-admin-console} | security-admin-console
 ${client_admin-cli}              | admin-cli
                                  | app3
                                  | app1
 example Realm                    | example-realm
                                  | app2
 ${client_realm-management}       | realm-management
 ${client_account}                | account
                                  | demo
 ${client_account-console}        | account-console
 ${client_broker}                 | broker
 ${client_security-admin-console} | security-admin-console
 ${client_admin-cli}              | admin-cli
```

[image]

#### #9 Step 9, realms list and detail information

```
SELECT name, id, access_code_lifespan FROM realm;
```

-->

```
  name   |                  id                  | access_code_lifespan
---------+--------------------------------------+----------------------
 master  | master                               |                   60
 example | e78f0c77-b44b-48da-850b-9d157e24a439 |                   60
```

[image]

#### #10 Step 10, list user

```
SELECT * FROM user_entity;
```

-->

```
                  id                  | email |           email_constraint           | email_verified | enabled | federation_link | first_name | last_name |               realm_id               |       username       | created_timestamp |     service_account_client_link      | not_before
--------------------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------+----------------+---------+-----------------+------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------+------------
 c028a1c0-c9e1-449c-a7b4-2bcc0209748f |       | fe9c8176-c624-46c4-adcf-26f97bfd7c47 | f              | t       |                 |            |           | master                               | admin                |     1663581309951 |                                      |          0
 d87bf317-62fa-42c7-a97e-d354b5f8abab |       | 849e6b1c-ee36-49af-8d86-db273571136f | f              | t       |                 |            |           | e78f0c77-b44b-48da-850b-9d157e24a439 | service-account-demo |     1671620871610 | 5ccdb298-b68e-433b-a09e-27b417bc5bd7 |          0
 22286745-ca01-4e79-9ead-bf87b6d3ef42 |       | 47fac099-52e2-4baa-b97e-a260cbc293bd | f              | t       |                 |            |           | e78f0c77-b44b-48da-850b-9d157e24a439 | user2                |     1671585500197 |                                      |          0
 f2b7cd6b-7f6c-4f77-b2f8-a8f406a9fec4 |       | 0b2edfb4-476c-40c5-a83f-77c7998e3417 | f              | t       |                 |            |           | e78f0c77-b44b-48da-850b-9d157e24a439 | user3                |     1671586002650 |                                      |          0
 4c220068-dba4-414f-909d-979d549e8824 |       | 432e3b6c-9697-49ef-bfde-da6e6ba86308 | f              | t       |                 |            |           | e78f0c77-b44b-48da-850b-9d157e24a439 | service-account-app3 |     1669770194446 | b06ed222-f458-4bb5-aeda-7a7ef759ce79 |          0
 d9bb2e1e-47b1-417b-b62c-c91ee9903823 |       | 6ca1dd29-4f5b-4fb8-a860-52db1a6afecb | f              | t       |                 |            |           | e78f0c77-b44b-48da-850b-9d157e24a439 | service-account-app1 |     1669770220095 | 291ebd07-f061-4a73-84aa-43bffe9d04cb |          0
 7f46d52f-130c-4b18-9a73-bc1617edac09 |       | 86e5372e-ca08-4616-8191-cc7f15806744 | f              | t       |                 |            |           | e78f0c77-b44b-48da-850b-9d157e24a439 | service-account-app2 |     1669770245105 | f931e207-820a-4f19-b9e5-255be90366ed |          0
 2b397d5d-2c54-4cb9-932d-9fdd18d018ba |       | 117960f6-5071-42d3-b052-f9e9f420468b | f              | t       |                 |            |           | e78f0c77-b44b-48da-850b-9d157e24a439 | test                 |     1670617022033 |                                      |          0
 417a6295-08b4-4bcc-86a8-ce2c1f158ede |       | b835e6a9-627a-414c-9d05-00748afadc47 | f              | f       |                 |            |           | e78f0c77-b44b-48da-850b-9d157e24a439 | user1                |     1671585149910 |                                      |          0
```

[image]

#### References

[PostgreSQL: Show tables in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769683/postgresql-show-tables-in-postgresql)

[PostgreSQL Show Tables](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-administration/postgresql-show-tables/)