# Brute force protection in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to implement brute force protection in keycloak. I am able to implement it via the admin console. However, I am not able to find where keycloak stores details of temporariliy locked users in keycoak. I am using keycloak 21.0.0. Any idea on the tables where the data of brute force is stored at keycloak's end will be immensely helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not a good idea directly to access internal(or external) databases due to security and can't use sync DB trigger. Good ideas are using [REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/20.0.2/rest-api/index.html#_attack_detection_resource) or [SPI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_providers)

Comment: I am trying to find out which table of keycloak DB stores the temporary and permanently locked users to better understand the work flow. Nothing wrong in doing that. I am aware of the APIs to get the locked user details. Thanks anyways for replying.

Comment: The `event_entity` (regular user list information) table 's `error` column has a information `user_temporarily_disabled`  or `invalid_user_credentials` or permanently locked when hit the maximum number of Login Failures. Not the `username_login_failure` table. you can see how to access keycloak tables and content in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74962002/data-from-spring-application-is-not-being-persisted-in-the-dockerized-postgres-d/74967322#74967322).

Comment: @BenchVue - I am able to see a column by name "ERROR" in "EVENT_ENTITY". However, the column has no entry even though the user is temporarily blocked for 1 day. Are you getting any entry as "user_temporarily_disabled" ? I am using mySql.

Comment: I tested mySQL 5.7 and Keycloak V19.0.3 by docker compose. The `permanentLockout` in USER_ATTRIBUTE table (VALUE column) and `invalid_user_credentials` or `user_disabled` in `EVENT_ENTITY` table (EVENT_ENTITY column)

Comment: Sorry typo the last was wrong it should be (error column).

Comment: @BenchVue - Thanks for your reply. I double checked but cant find any entry in either "USER_ATTRIBUTE" or "EVENT_ENTITY". I am using keycloak 21. I checked if infinispan is caching the data and not sending to persisting DB - thats not the case as well. I will continue to check further.

Comment: I will try it for V21.0.0 I don't know the cache involve or not. If yes, that I said why  DB approaches is not good method even if to understand better by low level flow.

Comment: Can you share the docker-compose.yml file? I have no both support V21 and mySQL with docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: @BenchVue - thank you. I have disabled caching of user details. the problem persists. Even though the temporaray lock feature works perfectly fine, for some reason, I dont see the data in the tables mentioned by you. I am running keycloak in embedded springboot app, i believe, my docker-compose wont work at your end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254878/discussion-between-jane-and-bench-vue).

Comment: I tested MariaDB V10 and Keycloak V 21.0.0.  The `temporarily locked users` is in `EVENT_ENTITY` at `ERROR` column. And  The `permanentLockout` is in `USER_ATTRIBUTE` table at `VALUE` column.

Comment: Thanks for your accepting, can you vote me too? It will make me happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Permanent Lock Information

Permanent Lock Information is `USER_ATTRIBUTE` table at `VALUE` column

```
MariaDB [keycloak]> SELECT * FROM USER_ATTRIBUTE;
+----------------+------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| NAME           | VALUE            | USER_ID                              | ID                                   |
+----------------+------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| disabledReason | permanentLockout | a0cbe53b-26b2-4bd1-981a-0abac0a72483 | 8ac10d9d-ab07-4a02-9f31-b647b7ecff48 |
+----------------+------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

[image]

UI Setting for `Permanent Lock` in Keycloak (*Figure 2)
[image]

[image]

#### user_temporarily_disabled

The `user_temporarily_disabled` is in `EVENT_ENTITY` Table at `ERROR` column

Simple `EVENT_ENTITY` Table (just 3 columns)

```
-+---------------------------+----------------+------------------------------
 | ERROR                     |  TYPE          | USER_ID
-+---------------------------+----------------+------------------------------
 | NULL                      |  LOGOUT        | c3fecc20-5fb3-4a02-be85-988b5
 | NULL                      |  LOGOUT        | 013cb4da-bb6f-487a-ba3b-a60fe
 | NULL                      |  CODE_TO_TOKEN | 013cb4da-bb6f-487a-ba3b-a60fe
 | invalid_user_credentials  |  LOGIN_ERROR   | 013cb4da-bb6f-487a-ba3b-a60fe
 | user_temporarily_disabled |  LOGIN_ERROR   | 013cb4da-bb6f-487a-ba3b-a60fe
 | NULL                      |  LOGIN         | 013cb4da-bb6f-487a-ba3b-a60fe
 | invalid_user_credentials  |  LOGIN_ERROR   | 013cb4da-bb6f-487a-ba3b-a60fe
 | invalid_user_credentials  |  LOGIN_ERROR   | 013cb4da-bb6f-487a-ba3b-a60fe
-+---------------------------+----------------+------------------------------
```

Full `EVENT_ENTITY` Table

```
MariaDB [keycloak]> SELECT * FROM EVENT_ENTITY;
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+---------------+------------------------------
--------+
| ID                                   | CLIENT_ID       | DETAILS_JSON                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        | ERROR                     | IP_ADDRESS | REALM_ID                             | SESSION_ID                           | EVENT_TIME    | TYPE          | USER_ID
        |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+---------------+------------------------------
--------+
| 079a5ca0-9ed2-41c1-81ad-c381bf2baa5a | NULL            | {"redirect_uri":"http://localhost:8080/realms/master/account/#/"}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   | NULL                      | 172.22.0.1 | 5f9b5416-259d-4c38-b27b-afb5d6200789 | ad2493fc-24c4-4299-834c-56878f0758af | 1691711078287 | LOGOUT        | c3fecc20-5fb3-4a02-be85-988b5
c686467 |
| 693e86d1-b749-4b77-8d90-8650b26853df | NULL            | {"redirect_uri":"http://localhost:8080/realms/master/account/"}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | NULL                      | 172.22.0.1 | 5f9b5416-259d-4c38-b27b-afb5d6200789 | b17cebed-0726-4092-ac73-531accf2da50 | 1691711091836 | LOGOUT        | 013cb4da-bb6f-487a-ba3b-a60fe
8898ea6 |
| 8b94431c-f7dc-415d-8c84-7ce3d654efc8 | account-console | {"token_id":"4e687bef-af48-4703-a3c2-07ad76f69b17","grant_type":"authorization_code","refresh_token_type":"Refresh","scope":"openid profile email","refresh_token_id":"7bf6871f-48dc-4e7b-8e9a-86027b70d261","code_id":"b17cebed-0726-4092-ac73-531accf2da50","client_auth_method":"client-secret"} | NULL                      | 172.22.0.1 | 5f9b5416-259d-4c38-b27b-afb5d6200789 | b17cebed-0726-4092-ac73-531accf2da50 | 1691711088224 | CODE_TO_TOKEN | 013cb4da-bb6f-487a-ba3b-a60fe
8898ea6 |
| 8dc34bfd-df10-46c1-8236-e0dc7ab513d1 | account-console | {"auth_method":"openid-connect","auth_type":"code","redirect_uri":"http://localhost:8080/realms/master/account/#/security/signingin","code_id":"9bbb5166-bffb-4ebe-b743-918ee1d1aea6","username":"user2"}                                                                                           | invalid_user_credentials  | 172.22.0.1 | 5f9b5416-259d-4c38-b27b-afb5d6200789 | NULL                                 | 1691711106048 | LOGIN_ERROR   | 013cb4da-bb6f-487a-ba3b-a60fe
8898ea6 |
| a42f9d00-2d86-4f8b-8ba5-75e6f6e91501 | account-console | {"auth_method":"openid-connect","auth_type":"code","redirect_uri":"http://localhost:8080/realms/master/account/#/security/signingin","code_id":"9bbb5166-bffb-4ebe-b743-918ee1d1aea6","username":"user2"}                                                                                           | user_temporarily_disabled | 172.22.0.1 | 5f9b5416-259d-4c38-b27b-afb5d6200789 | NULL                                 | 1691711108318 | LOGIN_ERROR   | 013cb4da-bb6f-487a-ba3b-a60fe
8898ea6 |
| ab50a625-9252-4de0-8d0b-825636a7afa0 | account-console | {"auth_method":"openid-connect","auth_type":"code","redirect_uri":"http://localhost:8080/realms/master/account/#/security/signingin","consent":"no_consent_required","code_id":"b17cebed-0726-4092-ac73-531accf2da50","username":"user2"}                                                           | NULL                      | 172.22.0.1 | 5f9b5416-259d-4c38-b27b-afb5d6200789 | b17cebed-0726-4092-ac73-531accf2da50 | 1691711086823 | LOGIN         | 013cb4da-bb6f-487a-ba3b-a60fe
8898ea6 |
| ad370ce8-77cf-435d-b718-2d773ca1c5f8 | account-console | {"auth_method":"openid-connect","auth_type":"code","redirect_uri":"http://localhost:8080/realms/master/account/#/security/signingin","code_id":"9bbb5166-bffb-4ebe-b743-918ee1d1aea6","username":"user2"}                                                                                           | invalid_user_credentials  | 172.22.0.1 | 5f9b5416-259d-4c38-b27b-afb5d6200789 | NULL                                 | 1691711100798 | LOGIN_ERROR   | 013cb4da-bb6f-487a-ba3b-a60fe
8898ea6 |
| bc74260c-ad1b-49f5-b2dd-7b13723eba25 | account-console | {"auth_method":"openid-connect","auth_type":"code","redirect_uri":"http://localhost:8080/realms/master/account/#/security/signingin","code_id":"9bbb5166-bffb-4ebe-b743-918ee1d1aea6","username":"user2"}                                                                                           | invalid_user_credentials  | 172.22.0.1 | 5f9b5416-259d-4c38-b27b-afb5d6200789 | NULL                                 | 1691711103367 | LOGIN_ERROR   | 013cb4da-bb6f-487a-ba3b-a60fe
8898ea6 |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------------+---------------+------------------------------
--------+
```

The `user_temporarily_disabled` is in `EVENT_ENTITY` Table at `ERROR` column

[image]

UI Event Logs for user2 login failed
[image]

UI Setting for  `user_temporarily_disabled` of `Brute force detection` (*Figure 3)
[image]

##### Demo `docker-compose.yml`

For Keycloak V21.0.0 and `mariadb V10`

```yaml
services:
  mysql:
    image: docker.io/mariadb:10
    container_name: my_mysql
    environment:
      MARIADB_DATABASE: keycloak
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: password
      MARIADB_USER: keycloak

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.0.0
    container_name: my_keycloak
    environment:
      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HOSTNAME_PORT: 8080
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_BACKCHANNEL: "true"
      KC_DB: mariadb
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:mariadb://mysql:3306/keycloak?characterEncoding=UTF-8
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: "true"
      KC_LOG_LEVEL: info
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080/health/ready" ]
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 15
    command: start-dev
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

##### Run it

```
docker compose up
```

##### Access mySQL Database to see tables and contents

```
docker exec -it my_mysql mysql -u root -p keycloak

or (if use Windows git bash shell)

winpty docker exec -it my_mysql mysql -u root -p keycloak
```

You needs to enter password (password is `password`)

```
password
```

[image]

Connect `keycloak` database

```
connect keycloak;
```

[image]

Show tables

```
show tables;
```

[image]

##### User Event monitoring setup

[image]

##### Permanent Lock

Setting UI for Permanent Lock (upper image - Figure 2)

Select `Impersonate` for `user1` failed 3 times

##### Failed login

Setting UI for `user_temporarily_disabled` (upper image - Figure 3)

Select `Impersonate` for `user2` failed 3 times

[image]

[image]

Show the `USER_ENTITY` table for Getting User list

```
SELECT * FROM USER_ENTITY;
```

[image]

Show the `USER_ATTRIBUTE` table

```
SELECT * FROM USER_ATTRIBUTE;
```

[image]

Show the `EVENT_ENTITY` table

```
SELECT * EVENT_ENTITY;
```

Result is already posted in upper.

Comment: You are welcome, I also learn a lot from your question.

Comment: I was looking for the same. Temporary lockout being recorded only in the event log implies that this timeout is only tracked in memory and is not persistent. Indeed, if I restart Keycloak I can log directly back in under the affected account.