# Documentation of KeyCLoak DB structure

Tags: keycloak, documentation, db-schema

Hello Keycloak masters,

I reverse engineered Postgres DB structure of KeyCloak into EnterpriseArchitect and I need to understand what the tables/attributes means.

Exist any documentation of keycloak DB schema? Descriptions of tables, attributes etc.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can it in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74962002/data-from-spring-application-is-not-being-persisted-in-the-dockerized-postgres-d/74967322#74967322)